# Facebook Login dialog permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Which permission is the "friend list" that I see on Zynga Poker?

(on api V2.2 oauth)

As I know, above 1.0 it's not possible to get non-app friends..
[image]

Comment: It is the user_friends permission that gives app friends

Answer (score -1):

**ANSWER EDITED:**

-- This is a misconception that friend list is an extended permission and it uses the `read_friendlists` permission i.e

> Friend List /{friendlist-id}
>
> A friend list - an object which refers to a grouping of friends
>   created by someone or generated automatically for someone (such as the
>   "Close Friends" or "Acquaintances" lists). You can view all of a
>   person's friend lists using the /{user-id}/friendlists edge.
>
> Permissions
>
> A user access token with `read_friendlists` permission is required to
>   view any of that person's friend lists.

**UPDATE** **-- Actual answer**

The above answer I've written is incorrect and I will be tagging that as common misconception so other users find it helpful. @WizKid's comment is correct. 
Here is a facebook [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440) report I dug up on official word on it

> The error which was being tracked in this bug report was that a
>   'access your friends list' prompt was appearing incorrectly as a
>   separate permission when no extra permissions were being requested -
>   this was resolved on August 21st 2013
>
> Note that currently the most basic level of permission grantable (i.e
>   with no extra scopes) grants access to the list of a user's friends
>   and their public profile information - some of the comments are
>   suggesting that this is an error, but it is not.
>
> The message in the auth dialog for this case says  " will
>   receive the following info: your public profile and friend list."

Slightly confusing, but `user_friends` a basic permission does say `friend list` in the permissions window

Its confused quite a few users -> Duplicate bugs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/521851941219283/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/237765679708244/)